# creating a function in Javascript with callback arguments

Tags: javascript, function, callback, arguments, arrow-functions

I want to create "foo" function  which has a callback as argument, and also wanted the callback to have two arguments as mentioned below. I tried, but didn't get a solution yet.

it doesn't have any usecase it's just a challenge for myself :)

```
function foo(callback){
      callback();
}
foo((arg1,arg2)=> {
      arg1=0;
      arg2=1;
});
```

what should i do?

Comment: please add the use case as well. where do hand over the parameters of the callback?

Comment: how do you expect to use `foo`?

Comment: actually i just want to learn how to create a function like this, because i saw some functions like this in NodeJs and jQuery and it's use case is not important in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments passed to the callback are created *by the function calling it*, so in your case `foo` does that:

```js
function foo(callback){
      callback(/*arg1: */ 0, /* arg2: */ 1);
}

foo((arg1,arg2) => {
   console.log("arg1 is", arg1, "arg2 is", arg2);
});
```

You call a callback just like you call any other function.

Answer (score 0):

fixed.

this is what i learned and i want to share with you,
to create a simple callback function we can write:

```
function foo(DoSomeThing){
     DoSomeThing();
}
```

and to test that :

```
foo(function(){
      console.log(`Hello world`);
});
```

this function didn't have any arguments, so if we want to add arguments we shuold do something like :

```
function foo2(doSomeThing){
      doSomeThing(argument1=0,argument2=0);
}
```

and to test that :

```
foo2((arg1,arg2) => {
      console.log(`arg1 : ${arg1} and arg2 : ${arg2}`);
});
```

in this case answer is : `arg1 : 0 and arg2 : 0`

in the first example i used callback function and in the second one i used arrow function.it depends on you to choose any of them...